How do i stop FullCalendar from refetching my events after pressing the next/prev buttons?
I'm using FullCalendar with Laravel, every time I'm trying to go next/prev its recalling my ajax call for the events, how can i prevent this from happening? I want it to fetch the events once, and only when I select the checkboxes for the other calendars to merge them together.
Here is my code:
    $(".calendar_list").each(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            selectedCalendars.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
        lazyFetching: true, // tried with and without
        headerToolbar: {
            left: 'prev,next today addEventButton',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        events: {
            url: SITEURL + '/calendarsAjax',
            method: 'GET',
            extraParams: {
                calendar_ids: selectedCalendars
            },
            success: function() {
            },
            failure: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        },
    });
  calendar.render();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    getCalendar();
});

I've tried lazyloading, it still occurs.

The next and previous buttons in Fullcalendar load new days, weeks, months, etc., and it tries to load the events for this new visible date range. I would recommend letting it do that; loading every event into memory is fine until you have too many events and not enough memory (and who knows when that is).

I agree with Tim Lewis' comment...why would you want to prevent this? This is how it's intended to work.
What you possibly haven't realised is that (as per the JSON events feed documentation) fullCalendar will send your server "start" and "end" parameters with each request, representing the earliest and latest date currently being displayed on the calendar. Your server is supposed to use these to filter its data and only return event data which falls within or overlaps those dates.
That's generally a lot more efficient than just downloading every event in your database when the calendar is first loaded - because that list of events will grow hugely over time, and in most cases the user is probably never going to look at the vast majority of them. Therefore you should want it to only download events which are likely to be relevant, and do that on-demand when the user is actually going to see them.
P.S. The lazyFetching option - again as per the documentation - only reduces the volume of AJAX calls, by not loading events when the calendar has already fetched events for the same date range previously. It does not prevent them from occurring at all.
